# Segfaulting when custom SIGTERM handler is used

Tags: php, symfony, signals

I have a PHP script that runs indefinitely, and I'm trying to make it so that it can gracefully shut down when it receives a SIGTERM signal. This script is part of a large Symfony2 codebase, so the "script" is actually a service that's being started by a command. Basically, I have a boolean in the service class `$shouldBeAlive`. I have a `while(true)` loop that checks if `$shouldBeAlive` is still true at the start of every iteration. I then have a signal handler that is set just before the `while(true)` loop is started that, if a SIGTERM is thrown, sets `$shouldBeAlive` to false, so that the loop will finish its current iteration and then exit immediately at the start of the next iteration.

In my understanding of signals and whatnot, all this should work fine. But instead, I get a message `Segmentation fault: 11` every time I send a SIGTERM to the php process (which I do with `kill <pid>`). I've tried using Xdebug traces to find the source of the issue, but I couldn't figure out an obvious issue from that (also, the trace file Xdebug is generating is 8-10MB).

Here's a simplified version of my service class:

```
class WorkerService extends AbstractService
{
    private $shouldBeAlive;

    // called by the constructor of this class
    protected function setup()
    {
        $this->shouldBeAlive = false;
    }

    // called when my command wants to make the work begin
    public function go()
    {
        $this->shouldBeAlive = true;

        // set signal handler to `$this->handleSignal($signo)`
        assert(pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, [$this, "handleSignal"]));

        $this->work();
    }


    public function handleSignal($signo)
    {
        // make the worker terminate on next loop completion
        $this->shouldBeAlive = false;

        // restore the default handler for this signal
        assert(pcntl_signal($signo, SIG_DFL));

        echo "Signal received, shutting down gracefully... (send signal again to force immediate shutdown)";
        return;
    }

    public function work()
    {
        while (true) {
            // make PHP fire any waiting signals
            pcntl_signal_dispatch();

            // break out of the loop if we're supposed to be dead
            if (!$this->shouldBeAlive) break;

            // ...
            // I'm omitting the actual loop logic. Basically, it makes some
            // HTTP requests, sometimes starts another process with proc_open(),
            // and eventually it'll sleep for a couple seconds and continue.
        }
    }
}
```

It seems like my handleSignal($signo) method never gets called at all, as no amount of tweaks to it fix the issue. I've also tried using `declare(ticks = 1);` in the go() method instead of calling `pcntl_signal_dispatch();` in the while(true) loop, and it still segfaults (and, the way I understand things, doing it that way doesn't make sense anyway). Does anyone see what I might be missing or misunderstanding?

Comment: Segmentation fault: 11 -- Sounds like php actually crashes. try to move the echo to the start of the signal handler, to see if there are any of the things you do inside the handler that causes the crash / bug in php.

Comment: @Stian Skjelstad It's been a while, but I think I tried that, and found that the function was never getting called at all.